# Can multiple Sony Smartwatch 2 be paired to one Android device?

Tags: nfc, sony, sony-smartwatch

This isn't your typical smart watch application...

Restaurants are busy places, and our app is doing everything we can to make it easier for the staff to communicate with the host stand. One of the issues with having an 'app' for the bussers to update table status from dirty to clean is that they have to open the phone, unlock it, tap, lock, put it back in their pocket.

From what I understand, the Sony Smartwatch 2 could do what I want, but the problem is the cost involved. For each buss boy to have a $200 smart watch and a phone in their pocket is nuts. Is it possible to have multiple Smartwatches hooked up to one device?

All I want to do is read the NFC tag and push a change to our servers using wifi. Ultimately, it's pretty simple but no doubt a challenging proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Bluetooth allows just one device of specific type to be connected at once. This behavior is related to Bluetooth profiles limitation.

Your use-case sounds really interesting! Try to think about using your staff private phones. You can connect SmartWatch to any Android (4.0.3+) smartphone with Smart Connect application installed (not only Sony smartphones).

Comment: To add to this, Android phones can be found pretty cheap these days especially if buying used (would think less than $50) and they don't need to have a data plan since communication can be done over WiFi so the cost of each person having a phone in their pocket would be pretty small, especially compared to the price of the watch.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this could be done, BT has a range of 10m. This would be very limiting in a restaurant.

Alternative solution: Presumably the bus boys bring plates to a central place, place a rugged android tablet (or at least a waterproof tablet) on a wall there so they can quickly mark tables as clean.